# Form is not executing submit function

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, react-apollo, semantic-ui-react

The code in my `onSubmit` function is never executed nor getting any errors. I am using Semantic-UI-React with graphql/mongoDB backend with apollo as client. The front end framework is Next.js. Any help as to why it is not entering the submit function is much appreciated!

Whole component class:

```
class EmployeeForm extends Component {
    state = {
        name: "",
        employeeID: "",
        mnemonic: "",
        errorMessage: "",
        loading: false
    }

    onSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('entering function');

        const newEmployeeWallet = ethers.Wallet.createRandom();
        this.setState({mnemonic: newEmployeeWallet.mnemonic});

        const {employeeID} = this.props;
        const mnemonic = this.state.mnemonic;
        await this.props.createEmployee({
            variables: { 
                employeeID, 
                mnemonic, 
            },
        }); 
        console.log(this.state.mnemonic);
        console.log(newEmployeeWallet.address); 

    };

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h3>Authenticate a new Employee</h3>
                <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} error={!!this.state.errorMessage}>                    
                    <Form.Field inline>
                        <Input label='Name' placeholder='Name' value={this.state.name} required={true} onChange={event => 
                        this.setState({ name: event.target.value })}/>
                    </Form.Field> 
                    <Form.Field inline>
                        <Input label='Employee ID' placeholder='Employee ID' value={this.state.employeeID} required={true} onChange={event =>
                        this.setState({ employeeID: event.target.value})}/>
                    </Form.Field> 
                    <Message error header='Error!' content={this.state.errorMessage} />          
                    <Button loading={this.state.loading} type='submit' primary>Submit</Button>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const createEmployee = gql`
            mutation createEmployee($employeeID: String!, $name: String!) {
                createEmployee(input: {employeeID: $employeeID, name: $name}) {
                    employeeID
                    name
                }
            }
        `;

export default graphql(createEmployee, { name: 'createEmployee'})(EmployeeForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using ES6 classes for your React Component, your methonds don't get autobinded to your component instance so you need to do it manually either in the constructor(preferably) or in your method call:

```
<Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)} ...
```

This could solve your problem if you don't have other problem elsewhere. Read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#autobinding